# how to disable the hierarchy viewer in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

Guys I just happened to come across this new feature in eclipse wherein I can run the hierarchy viewer from within eclipse but, I couldn't make it work .

I did search on the net but nothing is written except for how to run it from the tools directory. So anyways I was stretching my luck and finally when I got the application running ,now before installing the application into the emulator it tries to connect the hierarchy viewer to the emulator which eventually it fails to connect.(It shows up in the console)

Now my problem is that the emulator from the start was very bad with the start up time which I somehow tolerated until now but, now after this it takes even more time to start up. I think I  have messed up a setting somewhere trying to get the hierarchy viewer working within eclipse but, just can't remember it.

I am getting all this in the console window in eclipse

```
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server version from device emulator-5554
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to get view server protocol version from device emulator-5554
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - ddms]execute: running service call window 1 i32 4939
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - ddms]execute 'echo $EXTERNAL_STORAGE' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - ddms]execute: returning
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - ddms]execute: running echo $ANDROID_DATA
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - ddms]execute 'echo $ANDROID_DATA' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - ddms]execute: returning
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - ddms]execute: running echo $ANDROID_ROOT
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - ddms]execute 'service call window 1 i32 4939' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - ddms]execute: returning
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - ddms]execute 'echo $ANDROID_ROOT' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
[2012-01-31 01:08:57 - ddms]execute: returning
[2012-01-31 01:08:59 - ddms]execute: running service call window 1 i32 4939
[2012-01-31 01:08:59 - ddms]execute 'service call window 1 i32 4939' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
[2012-01-31 01:08:59 - ddms]execute: returning
```

[2012-01-31 01:08:59 - hierarchyviewer]Unable to debug device emulator-5554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by restarting windows or to be more specific eclipse itself.

Comment: getting the same error i have restarted the eclipse as well as windows but problem not solved how to disable it.